# How to increase size of horizontal scroll button in Toolstripmenuitem

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, toolstripmenu, toolstripdropdown

I have a Toolstripmenuitem similar to what is shown in this image:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to make the overflow scroll at the bottom and top larger so that it is easier to click?

Comment: Hmm, no, they are not horizontal scroll buttons.  You can't change their size.  We've been through this before, don't create context menus like this, they are horrible.

Comment: Is there a way to detect that the context menu if in overflow as shown in the image above?